# Draw colored checkers grid in python

Tags: python, image, colors, grid

i need to draw a colored checkers grid in an existing image, with colors taken from a list.
This is the code i have:

```
import image as im
def draw_gen_checkers(img, s, colors):
    n = 0
    for i in range(len(img)/s):
        for j in range(len(img[0])/s):
            for ii in range(i*s, i*s+s):
                for jj in range(j*s,j*s+s):
                    img[ii][jj] = colors[n]
            if n == len(colors)-1:
                n = 0
            else:
                n = n + 1
    im.visd(img)

img = im.create(300, 200, (0,0,0))
colors = [(255,128,0),(0,0,255),(0,255,0),(255,0,0)]
s = 25
```

With this code this is the result i get:[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrfSD.png)

When the image should look like this:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4CNO.png)

Ty all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to see your work progress :)

Let's do the math : your picture is 300px long, your cases are 25px long, so you have 12 cases per line, since you have 4 colors you have 12 // 4 == 3 color rotations by line, but since 12 % 3 == 0, when you start your new line, your n is back to 0. And nowhere you say that you want an increasing offset for colors in each line, so all your lines are the same.

Just adding a n increment at the start of each line should do the trick.

For your n increment, instead of using an if-else people often use the modulo operator `n = (n+1) % len(colors) # 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, ...`

edit: when I said 'adding a n increment at the start of each line' I was thinking of something like that (i think it should be good):

```
def draw_gen_checkers(img, s, colors):
    n = 0 # Alternatively n = len(colors)
    for i in range(len(img)/s):
        n = (n + 1) % len(colors)
        for j in range(len(img[0])/s):
            for ii in range(i*s, i*s+s):
                for jj in range(j*s,j*s+s):
                    img[ii][jj] = colors[n]
            n = (n + 1) % len(colors)
```

The drawback would be that the first color you use will be the second in your list since it increments n before everything else. Depending on what you do it could be a problem or not, if it is you can initialize n to len(colors)-1 to fix it.

I would also create a function draw_square(i, j, s, c), with your 2 most inner loops, that would make the code more readable and more modular (this function would probably be useful somewhere else at some point).

Comment: Hello again, and ty again :) If you ever come to Rome i will bye you a beer my friend :D

Comment: i postet the code below as and answer. I would like if u checked it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
def draw_gen_checkers(img, s, colors):
n = 0
for i in range(len(img)/s + 1):
    for j in range(len(img[0])/s + 1):
        for ii in range(i*s, i*s+s):
            for jj in range(j*s,j*s+s):
                if 0 <= ii < len(img) and 0 <= jj < len(img[0]):
                    img[ii][jj] = colors[n]
        n = (n+1) % len(colors)
im.visd(img)

img = im.create(300, 200, (0,0,0))
colors = [(255,128,0),(0,0,255),(0,255,0),(255,0,0)]
s = 25
```

It prints:[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FfnJ.png)